# Using Spring boot JPA getting data from existing oracle db

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Hi I have an existing oracle db, which contains tables.
Need to get data from multiple tables using jpa from spring boot api below are my questions

1. Do I need model classes of those multiple tables or I don’t need model classes to get the required column data?
   2.Can I write a custom query joining multiple tables and get the list of values from my db using jpa?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to expose the query results as a spring boot rest API. You need to have some object definition to hold the query results into memory. It is always a good idea to have a model to represent your query results for better manageability and maintainability of code. Certainly, you can achieve it without creating any models by storing all the results into a Map.

If you don't use models then you will be missing key features of ORM tools.

Just to answer your questions -

1. Do I need model classes of those multiple tables or I don’t need model classes to get the required column data?

   **Answer:** Not required but recommended to use model classes.
2. Can I write a custom query joining multiple tables and get the list of values from my db using jpa?

   **Answer:** You can write the native SQL query by joining multiple tables.

You can find more examples [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-query-map-result/)